# DataGridView auto-edit mode on append

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview where the default values are provided for every new row being inserted. Sometimes defaults are 100% suitable for the new row and the record should be saved with no more changes. But if user simple leaves the row the record clears :( How can i auto-save the new row (or auto-set edit mode for it) to let user insert a new one?
Thanks!

Comment: you lost me after "But if user simple leaves the row the record clears :( How can i auto-save the new row (or auto-set edit mode for it) to let user insert a new one?"

Comment: User adds a new row to the grid just going to the empty record at the bottom of grid. The new row is automatically populated with defaults and user wants to save it as is with no additional changes. What he need to do for this? If user leaves that row, it disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to sometimes save a new record with the default cell values generated when the users adds a new row. You could intercept the lost focus event of the datagridview to check if there is such a new "default" row and store it on the database. But this method would **always** create a new row on the database, and you've said that sometimes the default values are not good enough. The only way to control that would be to ask the user with a dialog prompting if he wants to save the new "default" row, which could quickly turn into an annoyance.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes, you understand me well - i'm sorry for my english :) Other question is **how** to store any grid row to database? What method of row or grid should i call to perform that operation? I can catch event like RowLeave but i dont know what to do then.

Comment: With code like this: foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in grd.Rows[XXX].Cells) { var cellContent = cell.Value; } you access the values of all the cells in the row number XXX, assuming "grd" is the name of the DataGridView control. I don't know how you access the database for storing new records, but you'll have to use those values to do it, composing an entity object and storing it, or composing an SQL insertion query, or whatever.